# How to format the structure of data returned from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I got this data from my SQL query:

```
addon_id | addon_name | addon_category_id
---------+------------+------------------
       1 | abc        |                10
       2 | def        |                20
       3 | ghi        |                10
```

Now I have to send this in the following JSON format and group the addons based on `addon_category_id`:

```
[
 {
  addon_category_id: 10,
  addons:
  [
   {
    addon_id: 1,
    addon_name: abc
   },
   {
    addon_id: 3,
    addon_name: ghi
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  addon_category_id: 20
  addons:
  [
   {
    addon_id: 2,
    addon_name: def
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

How can I do this? What is the logic behind that? Do I have to do it programmatically using a `for` loop or is there any other way?

Comment: That would depend on the language you are using to retrieve this data. You can use general purpose tools as well, such as https://www.csvjson.com/sql2json

Comment: Thanks @JuanN, but I need to change the structure of data as I have shown above.

Comment: It depends on the programming language and database system you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it depends on the programming language you use. In SQL Server 2016 you can use **FOR JSON AUTO**

```
SELECT  b.addon_category_id  ,addons.addon_id ,  addons.addon_name
FROM addon a
JOIN  addon addons
ON a.addon_category_id  = b.addon_category_id  
FOR JSON AUTO;
```